# When is a Distribution a Measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, geometric-measure-theory

A distribution is of order $0$ if it is continuous for test function space with the maximal norm. Is that true that a distribution of order $0$ is the same thing as a measure?

This question is from Demailly's book 'Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry'.  On page 16 proposition (2.9), he says current of order $0$ can be regarded as forms with measure coefficient.(see the first sentence after the proof)

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is one of the versio s of the Riesz representation theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: @LL3.14 From Riesz representation theorem, the space of Radon measure is dual to $C_0(X)$(vanishing at inifity).  How to go from $C_0(X)$ to $C_c(X)$?

Comment: there are several versions of the RRT, so just use the one for $C_c$, at the beginning (rather than further down) on the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem